# Identify set in 12MB 16-way L3 cache with 64B cache lines

Tags: cpu, cpu-cache

The number of sets will be (12 * 2^20) / (16 * 2^6 ) = 3 * 2^12. Since the number of sets is not a power of two , how do the physical addresses map to the sets ?